# complex query without unionWith available

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

If I'm having an object `Post` with two properties

- `Title` of type string
- `IsHomePage` of type boolean
- `IsTagged` of type boolean

When using mongodb aggregation framework and `$unionWith` I can select in one DB round trip what I need (all docs where `IsHomePage` set to `true` and the rest for as many as it is with the property `IsTagged` set to `true`.

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    "$match": {
      IsHomePage: true
    }
  },
  {
    "$unionWith": {
      "coll": "collection",
      "pipeline": [
        {
          "$match": {
            IsHomePage: {
              $ne: true
            },
            IsTagged: true
          }
        },
        {
          "$sample": {
            "size": 50
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
])
```

How can I achieve the same for older MongoDB instance (where there is an older version than 4.4).

Note: [UnionWith is announced in version 4.4.](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/unionWith/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Query

- this can do what union does, but with the limitations of facet
  (each result array <16 MB the second is almost for sure because $sample)

*if its not what you want, if you can give sample data, and expected results
to write query + test it.

[PlayMongo](https://cmql.org/playmongo/?q=6228b275c2de7b441c4b4998)

```js
aggregate(
[{"$facet": 
    {"home": [{"$match": {"$expr": {"$eq": ["$IsHomePage", true]}}}],
      "notHome": 
      [{"$match": 
          {"$expr": 
            {"$and": 
              [{"$ne": ["$IsHomePage", true]}, {"$eq": ["$IsTagged", true]}]}}},
        {"$sample": {"size": 50}}]}},
  {"$project": {"union": {"$concatArrays": ["$home", "$notHome"]}}},
  {"$unwind": {"path": "$union"}},
  {"$replaceRoot": {"newRoot": "$union"}}])
```